# Perl: LWP::UserAgent Regarding rules for passing parameters

Tags: perl, curl

e.g.
I have a command

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" -X GET https://api.xxx/v1/datapackages/yyy
```

(1) I am confused when to use [ ] while passing the parameters. which one below is correct and why?

without [ ]

```
my $r2 = $ua -> get("https://api.xxx/v1/datapackages/yyy",
         'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         Authorization => 'Bearer '.$token,
);
```

or with [ ]

```
my $r2 = $ua -> get("https://api.xxx/v1/datapackages/yyy",
         [
         'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
         Authorization => 'Bearer '.$token,
         ]
);
```

(2) I see sometimes the parameter is quoted and sometimes not. Should "Authorization" be quoted and write as

with ' '

```
'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
```

or without ' '

```
Authorization => 'Bearer '.$token,
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [curl2lwp](https://corion.net/curl2lwp.psgi) can help you translate a curl command to a LWP incantation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `get()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#get) says this:

> **get**
>
> ```
> my $res = $ua->get( $url );
> my $res = $ua->get( $url , $field_name => $value, ... );
> ```
>
> This method will dispatch a GET request on the given URL. Further arguments can be given to initialize the headers of the request. These are given as separate name/value pairs. The return value is a response object. See [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response) for a description of the interface it provides.

So, that just talks about passing arguments as key/value pairs. It says nothing about using an array reference. So, if I were you, I'd stick with the first approach.

The "fat comma" (`=>`) is documented in [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) (because it's an operator) which says:

> The `=>` operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores. This includes operands that might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls. If in doubt about this behavior, the left operand can be quoted explicitly.
>
> Otherwise, the `=>` operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or list argument separator, according to context.

Basically, if the thing on its left is a single word (by which I mean a sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores), then you can omit the quote marks around it.

Comment: The array reference comes from post, probably.